# Oracle BPEL SOA - CUBE_SCOPE/DOCUMENT dehydration store contents

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

I have some queries concerning what bpel variables and values will be stored to Dehydration store in case oracle bpel. Consider I have an process "P1" with two scopes: an outer scope "s1" with variables "s1a,s1b,s1c" and within this s1 scope there is a nested inner scope "s2" with variables "s2a,s2b,s2c". When the process instance ends or if there is a wait activity at the end of outer scope s1, then the process state will be moved to dehydration store.

**My question here is would oracle soa server store all the variables of both scopes s1 and
s2 to dehydration store or since s2 scope is like a local loop within s1, would oracle   only persist variables and values of processes of the outer scope s1 alone?**

The reason why i ask is that the inner scope S2 in my process case handles a very huge xml of size more than 20 MB and i do not want this to be dehydrated to datastore at the end of process execution as this will fill up the soa table space quickly.

Comment: Oracle SOA & BPEL are products with small-ish developer communities.  So I suggest you try asking your question on the relevant Oracle TechNet forum, as you're more likely to find an expert there.  https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/fusion_middleware/soa_%26_process_management/bpel

Answer (score 2):

If the nested scope has finished processing then there is nothing to dehydrate in relation to that scope.  I am presuming that your nested scope is obtaining this large amount of data within the scope and disposing of it within the nested scope so the data would have no hold in the external scope.

This is of course presuming that the variables you use to store the data in the nested scope are contained within the nested scope and are not outer scope or global variables.